# The correct usage of "neither... nor"?

Tags: meaning, neither-nor

Is the usage of "neither... nor" natural in the following sentence?

> A: Are you an organized person?
>
> B: I am not the most organized person, but I'm neither procrastinator nor spontaneous. I tend to schedule things and plan my day in advance, but not every second of the day.

Comment: The word "but" sets up an opposition between "not the most organized" and "neither procrastinator nor spontaneous", which itself is an opposition. The meaning isn't very clear.

Comment: There is an opposition between being an organized person and being a procrastinator or spontaneous.  Organized people are typically not spontaneous.  Organized people are also not procrastinators.  I do think the second sentence is insufficiently linked, but I could still see someone saying it... it just reflects a certain set of (false) assumptions about what procrastination entails.

Comment: in case it wasn't clear to you, "neither ... nor" means exactly the same as "not ... and also not" so in this case "I'm not a procrastinator and also not spontaneous".

Comment: "neither ... nor ..." is used exactly like "either ... or ..." but with the opposite meaning.

Comment: It's also worth noting that _procrastinator_ is a noun and _spontaneous_ is an adjective.  They should not be used together (separated by a conjunction like you are using them.  You might say something like _"but I'm neither a procrastinator nor am I spontaneous"_, but it seems a bit awkward still

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the usage of "neither... nor" is natural in this sentence.  There is a grammatical mistake however, as "procrastinator" needs an article-- specifically, it needs to be "a procrastinator" here.

> I'm neither a procrastinator nor spontaneous.

The reverse order would also work.

> I'm neither spontaneous nor a procrastinator.

Content-wise, I am skeptical that "not being a procrastinator" is addressed in the following sentence... scheduling things and planning the day have nothing to do with procrastination.  That said, it's still a natural sentence, and would be idiomatic to a native or fluent speaker.

Comment: I think in poetic/literary contexts the article can actually be omitted; at least it sounds OK to my British English ears. Possibly influenced by the idiom "neither use nor ornament".

Comment: @muzer: Not to a Canadian ear (influenced by 30 years in the US).

Comment: @Muzer It _can_ be, but that clearly doesn't apply to this situation, and it's a very old-style folktale or biblical way of speaking. It's not worth mentioning here.